# Is it possible for the application to execute some code installation time?

Tags: installation

Just installed the application X. I never opened it. 
Is it possible for X to make some actions (execute some code) installation time, even though I never opened it.

In Windows when you install the app many things may be done. But Android is another beast.

Comment: Did you know that apps can be triggered by broadcasts even if they don't have an UI (i.e. can't be "opened")? It doesn't happen at install time, but it still qualifies as "executing stuff while you never opened it".

Comment: I am familiar with the concept of service https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services in Android, and yes @AndyYan it has lot of sense that app X which I am using in the question may have services. I am not sure if these services may be activated even before I open the app for the first time.